# DataSource Mbean in websphere liberty - getting instance not found exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-liberty, mbeans

I am trying to migrate WAS7 application to Liberty profile.
And now I am trying to get Datasource Mbean which is part of the existing code.I tried multiple options but I am always getting 'javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException'.

I am giving the sample code below. Please let me know if I miss something.

DataSource in Server.xml:

```
<library id="oracle-lib">
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="ojdbc6.jar"/>
</library>

<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/db" id="oracleDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <jdbcDriver javax.sql.DataSource="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource" libraryRef="oracle-lib" />
    <connectionManager agedTimeout="10" maxIdleTime="1800" connectionTimeout="180"  minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="1" reapTime="180"/>
    <properties.oracle user="user" password="password"
                url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//db-server:1521/db"/>
</dataSource>
```

Java Code:

```
MBeanServer mbeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName jvmQuery = new ObjectName("WebSphere:type=ConnectionPoolStats,name=dataSource[oracleDB]/ConnectionManager[default-0]")
Set mBeans = mbeanServer.queryMbeans(jvmQuery,null);
MBeanInfo beanInfo = mbeanServer.getMBeanInfo(jvmQuery);
```

I am not sure about the code, I am trying to keep the old code as much as possible.

Thank you,
Biju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your object name there is a minor case mismatch. The `C` on `connectionManager` should be lowercase, not uppercase.

```
WebSphere:type=ConnectionPoolStats,name=dataSource[oracleDB]/connectionManager[default-0]
```

A few other things to check:

1. Make sure you have the `monitor-1.0` feature enabled
2. Note that since Connection Managers are created lazily (not initialized until first use) there will be no `ConnectionPoolStats` MBean until there has been at least 1 connection obtained from your Connection Manager.
3. You can verify the presence of your MBean by checking `jconsole`, which is a Java utility that comes with any JDK. After a request has been made to your data source / connection manager, you should see an MBean like this:

[image]

To use `jconsole` you will need to enable the `localConnector-1.0` feature. You can find more info on using JConsole with Liberty here:
[Connecting to Liberty by using JMX](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_admin_jmx.html)

Comment: Thank you Andy..,C was a typo. I tried the above and it worked, Only thing is, I made small modifications to the ObjectName looking at the JConsole.